# Update nested variable field in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, phpstorm

Suppouse a **firestore Database** filled with this structure, being Events and Users collections:

```
Firestore
    -Events
        -1612483200
            -peopleSignedDict
                -Alex
                    -state: 1
                -Mark:
                    -state: 0
        -1606172400
            -peopleSignedDict                
    -Users
        -1zyXSMMlGiaUusUNLQWAxfsI4pM2
            -name: Alex
        -4zyXSMMlGiaUusUNLQWAxfsI4pM2
            -name: Mark
```

I'm using **Node.js** and trying to update `Events.1612483200.peopleSignedDict.Alex.state` to change the state from 1 to 0. To achieve it I'm trying to do:

```
var randomName = getRandomDBName();
db.collection('Events').doc('1612483200').set({
            'peopleSignedDict.'+randomName+'.state': 0
        });
```

But ofc my IDE (PhpStorm) yells at me telling that this syntax is not valid, which should be the correct syntax to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few way to do this.

My favorite is to first construct the key in a separate variable, and then use that in the collection:

```
let randomName = getRandomDBName();
let updates = {};
updates['peopleSignedDict.'+randomName+'.state'] = 0;
db.collection('Events').doc('1612483200').update(updates);
```

But a common (and shorter) alternative is:

```
let randomName = getRandomDBName();
db.collection('Events').doc('1612483200').update({ 
  [`peopleSignedDict.${randomName}.state`]: 0;
});
```

I'm actually not sure if the `[]` are needed in that last snippet, so if you have problems with it, try it without them and let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, you're the firebase-man to me! I've tested and without the [ ] won't work, it also works with [ ] and + instead of using $. But one question before accepting the answer, this currently creates a field called peopleSignedDict.Name.state instead of updating the value inside the Map, is the espected behaviour? Feels like this should be done using "update", instead of "set" maybe? Thanks again! ^^

Comment: Good catch. This should indeed have been an `update` call. I fixed it in my answer.